# iOS Copy to Clipboard from Browser

Tags: javascript, ios, web, clipboard, copy-paste

So a while back I was looking into a method of programatically copying something to the clipboard from a mobile website. It seemed impossible without using Flash in some way, which is of course not an option for iOS.

Then I came across this site https://getpocket.com/. As part of the setup process it instructs you create a bookmark, then it copies a new URL to your clipboard which you are then instructed to paste into the newly created bookmark.

So how does does this site do this on iOS devices? It was my understanding that this was not possible... Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no solution ((